# R loop completes only 3 iterations out of 2504

Tags: r, httr

I've written a function to download multiple files from NOAA's database. Firstly, I've got `sites` which is a list of site ID's that I want to download off the website. It looks like this:

```
 > head(sites)
   [[1]]
   [1] "9212"

   [[2]]
   [1] "10158"

   [[3]]
   [1] "11098"

> length(sites)
   [1] 2504
```

My function is shown below.

```
tested<-lapply(seq_along(sites), function(x) {
   no<-sites[[x]]
   data=GET(paste0('https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/paleo-search/data/search.json?xmlId=', no))
   v<-content(data)   
   check=GET(v$statusUrl)
   j<-content(check)
   URL<-j$archive
   download.file(URL, destfile=paste0('./tree_ring/', no, '.zip'))
 })
```

The weird issue is that it works for the first three sites (downloads properly), but then it stops after the three sites and throws the following error:

```
Error in charToRaw(URL) : argument must be a character vector of length 1
```

I've tried manually downloading the 4th and 5th site (using the same code as above, but not within function) and it works fine. What could be going on here?

EDIT 1: Showing more site ID's as requested

```
> dput(sites[1:6])
list("9212", "10158", "11098", "15757", "15777", "15781")
```

Comment: The data you share shows the IDs of the first 3 sites, which work. Could you share at least one more site so we see one that doesn't work? Preferably share with `dput` so we can make sure nothing is weird with your data structure. `dput(sites[1:6])` would be great.

Comment: @GregorThomas great suggestion, thanks! I've edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted your code to a `for` loop so I could see the most recent values of all your variables when things fail.

The fails aren't consistently on the 4th site. Running your code a few times, sometimes it fails on 2, or 3, or 4. When it fails, if I look at `j`, I see this:

```
$message
[1] "finalizing archive"

$status
[1] "working"
$message
[1] "finalizing archive"

$status
[1] "working"
```

If I re-run `check=GET(v$statusUrl); j<-content(check)` a few seconds later, then I see

```
$archive
[1] "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/web-content/paleo/bundle/1986420067_2020-04-23.zip"

$status
[1] "complete"
```

So, I think it takes the server a little bit of time to prepare the file for download, and sometimes R asks for the file before it's ready, which causes an error. A simple fix might look like this:

```
check_status <- function(v) {
  check <- GET(v$statusUrl)
  content(check)
}

for(x in seq_along(sites)) {
   no<-sites[[x]]
   data=GET(paste0('https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/paleo-search/data/search.json?xmlId=', no))
   v<-content(data)
   try_counter <- 0
   j <- check_status(v)
   while(j$status != "complete" & try_counter < 100) {
     Sys.sleep(0.1)
     j <- check_status(v)
   }
   URL<-j$archive
   download.file(URL, destfile=paste0(no, '.zip'))
}
```

If the status isn't ready, this version will wait 0.1 seconds before checking again, up to 10 seconds.

Comment: That's clever, thank you so much! It's good to know what the issue is! However, when I run your example it throws me an error: `Error in j : object 'j' not found`. I edited it by adding the previous two commands and it works great :))

Comment: It works great. Thanks a lot for your help! I've learnt something new thanks to you :)